# Create a function that creates object "X" with tokens imported from a csv file dynamically?

Tags: java

I have a few objects stored in multiple CSV files, and would like to:

1. Read the CSV file
2. Create objects based on the read tokens
3. Store and return the created objects into an arraylist.

Of course, creating separate functions for each object would be simple, but that would be tedious if I were to have a large number of objects to read in.

Is it possible to create a single function that is able to do all this dynamically?

Something like:

```
public ArrayList readFromCSV(String objectName){
  //generic all in one code
}
```

or

```
public ArrayList readFromCSV(Class classItself){
  //generic all in one code
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to do the opposite of the following:

```
public static void saveArray(String filename, List al) throws IOException {
    List alw = new ArrayList();// to store Professors data
    for (Object obj : al) {
        try {
            Class c = obj.getClass();
            Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
            int noOfFields = fields.length;
            StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfFields; i++) {
                // System.out.println("The field is: " + fields[i].getName());
                Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fields[i].getName());
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = field.get(obj);
                st.append(value.toString().trim());
                if (i != noOfFields - 1) {
                    st.append(SEPARATOR);
                }
            }
            alw.add(st.toString());
            write(filename, alw);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's quite close to what I'm looking for, but how would I go about adding different numbers of variables into constructor.newInstance() ?

Comment: Make the constructor accept an array of objects, this way you can choose how many parameters you give it.

Comment: Thank you so much for directing me toward the right link, I've managed to get it working now!